# Overlay div (added css) not cover Ionic header bar which paced inside ion-content

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I need to create a custom popup based on a dynamic `template`, `background`, and `actions`, to handle this created `div` overlay.

That `div` placed inside the `ion-content` and which is a mandatory requirement.

The overlay div can not cover header, it seems that the header has the highest z-index, which means it can not be covered by anything from the subpage.

The same issue posted over the ionic portal [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/overlay-guiding-full-screen-div-can-not-cover-tab-bar/122496) but the solution is not available.

Please find below the source code which using in my application.

```
<!---HTML source -->

<ion-app>
  <ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Hello</ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
 <ion-content>
       <div class="overlay">Test</div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-app>


/** css source */

.overlay {
         position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

https://ionic-angular-v5-ryaoho.stackblitz.io

Please help me to fix this issue using CSS.

Comment: Hi Santosh, can you elaborate what does not work for you? I reproduced it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5 and it does cover entire app? you had a typo and a few commas issues but that was it. Maybe I am missing something - please update your q

Comment: It’s working with simple Angular app but not working with ionic content

Comment: Can you add specifics and re-create the issue at stackblitz? otherwise its hard to help you

Comment: Sure let me add the code snippet

Comment: https://ionic-angular-v5-ryaoho.stackblitz.io

Comment: OK I see the demo but can you share exactly the code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the demo. I checked its source here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-ryaoho

And there is a comma in your CSS preventing the overlay to have z-index set correctly:

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99999, // here plz remove this comma

}
```

If you remove the comma you ll see that the overlay correctly does cover all content of the page including header.

Comment: That issue was because of header z-index which is more than overlay